# How to create a State vs. Death Bar Graph

Tags: python

File: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JNrPnC2YRg78ceblt1eeBN_Iz6rG2psE/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105308566456636539364&rtpof=true&sd=true

I am looking to create a Bar Graph Comparing State vs Death COVID 19 Data(Data is Attached) I have already filtered out the states and dates I want using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

datetime.datetime.strptime
df = pd.read_excel("Project.xlsx")
start = datetime.date(2020,10,31).strftime('%Y%m%d')
end = datetime.date(2020,12,1).strftime('%Y%m%d')
dfnew=df.query(f"{start} < date < {end}")
dfnew = dfnew.fillna('0')
dflatest = dfnew[(dfnew['state']=='GA')|(dfnew['state']=='IL')|(dfnew['state']=='CA')|(dfnew['state']=='NY')|
              (dfnew['state']=='NC')|(dfnew['state']=='MI')|(dfnew['state']=='OH')|(dfnew['state']=='FL')|
              (dfnew['state']=='PA')|(dfnew['state']=='TX')]
dflatest
```

However I am looking to get the average deaths (add up deaths per day) in the month of November by State. And Create a bar graph with X: State Y: Average Deaths in month of November I am not sure how to write out this code and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't see anything in your code that attempts to draw any kind of graph. Do you actually need help with understanding how to make `matplotlib` draw a graph? Or are you just trying to figure out how to prepare the data? If it's only about the data, then I don't understand exactly what the issue is. You should start by explaining the logical steps that you think are needed to solve the problem, and indicate which ones you aren't able to write code for, and what research you attempted to try to figure it out.

Comment: Hi, I believe that the code is already organized I would like the code on how to set up matplotlab. As well as use the group by function (which i am not able to understand)